# Why we're not use () at window.onload?

Tags: javascript, function

At end of this code ([full code is here](http://pastehtml.com/view/cdub7qdxd.html))

```
function addSongs() {
    var song1 = document.getElementById("song1");
    var song2 = document.getElementById("song2");
    var song3 = document.getElementById("song3");

    song1.innerHTML = "Blue Suede Strings, by Elvis Pagely";
    song2.innerHTML = "Great Objects on Fire, by Jerry JSON Lewis";
    song3.innerHTML = "I Code the Line, by Johnny JavaScript";
}
window.onload = addSongs;
```

You will see addSongs didn't used with ().

If i change it as

```
window.onload = addSongs();
```

It doesn't works. Why?

Comment: Because the parentheses executes the function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

when you have `addSongs()`, it's telling Javascript immediately execute that function and assign the return value of that call to the onload handler.

Without the `()`, it tells the JS engine to assign the function itself to onload.

e.g. if you had something like

```
function x() {
   return 'hello';
}

// immediately assigns "hello" to the onload
window.onload = x();
```

which is the same as doing

```
window.onload = 'hello';
```

and at some point the JS engine will try to execute a function named "hello", whenever the onload handler is triggered.

Comment: Thanks for all answers, guys.

Answer (score 1):

`addSongs` is a function, which you can assign to a variable (namely, in this case, `window.onload`). On the other hand, `addSongs()` is *calling* that function, and therefore you're setting `window.onload` to whatever `addSongs()` returns. Which is nothing, in this case.

Answer (score 1):

just like we assign int a = 5;
cuz we now know that a is an int and we can assign it a integer value like
similarly window.onload is a function , u can consider it to be of function type datatype
thus we can assign

```
window.onload=function(){ .. some code ... }
```

or we can use

```
function abc(){ ... some code ...}
window.onload=abc;
```

Answer (score 0):

When you use addSongs() it executes it right away instead of when it is being called.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're setting `onload` to be equal to the function.

If you call the function, then you're setting `onload` to be equal to the `return` value of the function (in this case, `undefined`).

Also, you have no control over when `onload/onready/onclick/etc` fire. That's the point.
You're asking the browser to fire the function when one of those things happen -- not before.